# Bluetooth keyboard not working with Windows 10

Tags: drivers, keyboard, windows-10, bluetooth

I've recently acquired a Microsoft Sculpt Mobile Keyboard and it works fine on Windows 7.

However, it doesn't work on Windows 10.

It is detected as a Bluetooth device, it asks me to type a pairing code and press enter (and this part works) and then it's displayed as being paired, but nothing happens when I press the keys. I've tried removing the drivers multiple times, rebooting and Windows installs the driver automatically after that, but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft, it isn't compatible with Windows 10.

[image]
[Larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjkMO.jpg)

This info was found at [Hardware Compatibility](https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/support/compatibility);

> Upgrading to Windows 10? Use the compatibility chart to find out which
>   products are compatible.

Comment: And isn't there a way to somehow install the driver in compatibility mode? (the driver isn't available for download though).

Comment: Not that I am aware of.